# вынести кусок кода отдельно

Tags: python

есть такой код:

```
def func():
while True:
    result = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/items?key=x').json()
    if result['items'] != 'null':
        m = len(result['items'])
        time.sleep(3)
        for x in range(m):
            itemid = result['items'][x]['item_id']
            classid = result['items'][x]['classid']
            hashname = result['items'][x]['market_hash_name']
            rewss = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/search-item-by-hash-name?key=x&hash_name=' + hashname).json()
            if rewss['data'] != []:
                k = len(rewss['data'])
                if result['items'][x]['position'] != 1:
                    if result['items'][x]['position'] != 0:
                        for j in range(k):
                            firstprice = min(rewss['data'], key=lambda x: x['price'])['price']
                            cla = min(rewss['data'], key=lambda x: x['price'])['class']
                            newprais = float(firstprice) - 1.0
                            time.sleep(3)
                            if hashname == rewss['data'][j]['market_hash_name']:
                                newprice1 = str(newprais)
                                currency = result['items'][x]['currency']
                                time.sleep(3)
                                r = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/set-price?key=x&item_id=' + itemid + '&price=' + newprice1 + '&cur=' + currency + '&')
                                print(r.text)
                                print(hashname)
                                func()
                            else:
                                func()
```

Скрипт повторяется если hashname == rewss['data'][j]['market_hash_name'] Как-то можно сделать чтобы не репитался,а продолжал?

Comment: А какую задачу выполняет Ваш код? Вынести то можно, например, создать функцию.

Comment: Скрипт повторяется если hashname == rewss['data'][j]['market_hash_name']
Как-то можно сделать чтобы не репитался,а продолжал?

Answer (score 1):

`т.е чтобы код не репитался после каждого запроса?` -
так может дело в рекурсии и её надо удалить?

```
def func:
    ...
        if hashname == rewss['data'][j]['market_hash_name']:
            ...
            func()  # <- рекурсия
        else:
            func()  # <- рекурсия
```

Comment: так он делает один и тот же запрос

Comment: вернее делает запрос примерно 5 раз подряд